# serious error with php move_uploaded_file not working

Tags: file-upload

i have a serious problem with php file upload. 
the problem is that the file is not moving from the tmp to the destination directory 
this is my html page

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="handleUpload.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="htmlfile">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and here is my PHP page handleUpload.php,

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{

    $arrayKeys=array_keys($_FILES['htmlfile']);
    foreach($arrayKeys as $s)
        echo $s ." : ".$_FILES['htmlfile'][$s]." <br>";
    $name = $_FILES['htmlfile']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['htmlfile']['size'];        
    $tempName= $_FILES['htmlfile']['tmp_name'];
    list($filePureName, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    $valid_formats = array("jpg","png", "gif", "bmp","rar","zip");
    $fileObject=fopen($tempName,"r") ;
        echo "test Text" . fgets($fileObject) ."</br>";
    fclose($dstFile) ;
    if($_FILES["htmlfile"]["error"] != 0 ) {
        echo "file error with code " .$_FILES["htmlfile"]["error"];
    }
    if( is_uploaded_file($tempName)){
        echo "<br> upladed to the tmp directory ";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["htmlfile"]["tmp_name"],"./".$_FILES["htmlfile"]["name"]) ;
        //move_uploaded_file($_FILES["htmlfile"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["htmlfile"]["name"])
    }

}
else{

    echo "you must visit the HTML upload page first";

}
```

the output i get is

```
name : numerical_hw1.rar 
type : application/octet-stream 
tmp_name : /tmp/phpK7Gmmf 
error : 0 
size : 34642 
test TextRar!Ïs WÅt K„Á &–Gá@3& numerical_hw1\hw1_q1\numerical_hw1.cpp°¸ EÌÌý•½¦~g†¡¹[•Í…Àk#€Qu{Q|0a®'#ÆàM¹%_ûánšF“Q‘Á®ÞÛÅ€ÁEq'‰\—ç9yq%Páðà;áy¹‰ùLx_,Xrh»qüÙ‰ÐO‰ †3JI²†Žc÷“4ˆ ‰‡oÉ²E³*[â¦†sÓè¤Í~·Ö”?ø‘ŒK6"Á¦æF,¼JÇ1rê¼´…BžT5$_sôJäÄ¼†Å$ýË¦A:`ë5kÎ­'3_„}ªœRÄ³Å3ÎÜøsÛV:÷5ËÎ°ãÚÓžõÌÚK¦œñÕ÷ÚßýT­vÙäÓ 

upladed to the tmp directory
```

the problem is that the file is not moved to the current directory nor to the "upload" directory -of course when it was alone and not commented- !! 
as you can see the file is uploaded successfully to the tmp directory and i have open it, and read a line from it. and also i have checked it with the is_uploaded_file function  and it pass that check.

i have carefully  read php file upload topics from many sites, and found nothing is missing in both php and html !! 
the folder permission is 755. 
i should mention here that file uploading was working before recently, and i am sure that no body has changed or modified the php.ini file.

**Any Help Please?? what should i do?**

**after exploring the server carefully i found that my website has been hacked, and the hacker upload a hack file !**
but really i don't know what to do now and also i cant estimate the damage size caused by that hacker so Any Suggestion ?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$pathDestino=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\\xxx\\upload\\" . $_FILES["htmlfile"]["tmp_name"];
$tmp_name=$_FILES["htmlfile"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $pathDestino);
```

Comment: You PHP is running in Linux or Microsoft?

Comment: ** my php code is working within a public server **
and i access my files through a cpanel and i don't know exactly what is the O.S on that server. but what ** am sure that i cant play with the php.ini**

Comment: I was have a similar situation with a site running in a Microsoft server hosted by 1&1, finally I change the provider and the problem disappear. Finally I see now you tmp_name have /, more like a path than a name. if you add the path what ends with a / with a name that begin with a /, you will have an error, try to echo the full path and see if properly formed.

Comment: I not think so. Have you check echoing the destination entire path? Is very probable the problem is there.